Python Subprocess - import file not found. I am able to execute child independently
I am on Python 3.12 and use venv. I have done pip install of PyMuPDF and able to use fitz pdf reader directly. However when I use subprocess to invoke the same program, i get an error that fitz not found.  Is there any other setting i need to do to use subprocess and use venv for the child process?
The below program is the child program and  works fine independently.
`import fitz
from pathlib import Path
def readfile(inpFilePath) :
f = fitz.open(inpFilePath)
print(len(f))
return
if name == "main" :
fpath = Path(file).parent.joinpath("t.pdf")
readfile(fpath)`
However when I invoke this program using subprocess function, i get error that fitz not found. What am I missing?
`import subprocess
import logging
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "./t1.py",
"t1.pdf"
])
log process PID
logging.info(f"Local job PID: {process.pid}")
`
I am new to trying subprocess.  any pointers are appreciated
